# about efficiency of std::cout in c++ and alternative ways to print message

Tags: c++, performance, cout

I'm learning C++, and as a exercise i am implementing a crude ASCII renderer, and my render function looks something like this:

```cpp
void render() {
    for(int y = 0;y < height;y++) {
        for(int x = 0;x < width;x++) {
            std::cout << getCharOfPixel(x, y);
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

but i wonder if it could be more efficient to store the whole thing in a string and just print out the whole string at once, like this:

```cpp
void render() {
    std::string finalString((width + 1) * height, '\0'); // initializing the string with ((width + 1) * height) null characters, to avoid resizing efficiency lack
    int characterIndex = 0; // where we are writing to finalString
    for(int y = 0;y < height;y++) {
        for(int x = 0;x < width;x++) {
            finalString[characterIndex++] = getCharOfPixel(x, y);
        }
        finalString[characterIndex++] = '\n';
    }
    std::cout << finalString;
}
```

more specifically, I'm asking if the efficiency of std::cout depends on how many characters i am writing or how many times i invoke it

Comment: You'd have to measure it to be sure, but in the case of outputting one string I would definitely not use `replace` for each character when `finalString[characterIndex++] = whatever;` is easier to read and perhaps faster. Again, something to measure.

Comment: While it should be faster to print one string directly, keep in mind that IO is *slow*, especially printing things to a console. Beside this, doing many `replace` can be quite slow too (but not as much as printing things).

Comment: What does `getCharOfPixel` do?  For additional readability, consider using `y` and `x` as loop variables instead of `i` and `j`.

Comment: Profile it. Where is it spending its time?

Comment: well... getCharOfPixel would do exactly what its name says... for a given pixel position, it returns the char that should be shown on the screen for this pixel.

Comment: It depends on the implementation, what buffering is used, and a few things like that.   As a rule of thumb, outputting a single large buffer of characters tends to be more efficient than a loop that outputs a small number of characters on each iteration.   But I/O is inherently slow, not matter how efficiently it is done, because it always involves devices that are much slower than the processor or memory of a system.   The preparation of data for output in non-trivial programs (or, more specifically, the algorithms used) tends to drive program efficiency more than I/O.